# WordPress 404 errors trying to display html5/javascript game in WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am trying to display html5/javascript code (as custom WP template) in a WordPress site to show html5 chess game. However I am plagued by referencing problems giving 404 errors.
This can be seen online @ 
http://www.buryknightschess.org.uk/play-chess/

I am grateful for help & advice to fix these errors to get the pagereferencing correct & display this game in my WordPress page.

(BTW this game comes from html5chess @ sourceforge & I can link to the demo there in my WordPress page & that displays properly. However I have edited the code from there & I would like to hard code this into my WordPress page if possible!). Thanks

UPDATE:
I am making progress now in that I have managed to get my chessboard displaying & working in WebMatrix localhost server. I use a custom WordPress page template with  php code to point to WP theme root directories & now these links are correct it works! I do need minor css adjustments to centre the pieces on squares/divs but I can play around with that & other minor page edits. Next stage is to make these edits on the online website but I am more confident of success now. Initially I thought it maybe WordPress blocking JavaScript calls but I think it is simply a matter of adding the JS links correctly! I will post again when I have it working online.

Comment: Did you attach js scripts properly to this theme?

Comment: Hi ninjaaa- Well the WP theme is my customised version of WordPress 2011 & I guess that handles JavaScript properly. Anyway I am making progress now I have scripts linked/referenced properly-see my UPDATE above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reviewing my StackExchange posts and checking whether my queries have been answered. This post is very old & remained as an unanswered post except I have answered it in my edit to my post above and so my post here now is simply to confirm I answered my own question!